# Angular JS Date filter not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an `ng-repeat` element which will loop through `$http.get()` result.

```
<tr ng-repeat="blog in posts">
     <td style="text-align:center">{{ $index+1 }}</td>
     <td>{{ blog.title }}</td>
     <td>
         {{ blog.author.name }}
     </td>
     <td>
         {{ blog.created_at | date:'MMM-dd-yyyy' }}
     </td>
</tr>
```

I have `created_at` as `timestamp` in MySQL database table. And I am using `angular.js  v1.0.7`.

I am getting the same output from db table and date filter is not working. How can I solve this?

My ajax call,

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost/app/blogs'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.posts = data.posts;
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.posts = [];
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the server side, it returns the `created_at` as string from the laravel eloquent.

This can be solved using this javascript,

```
new Date("date string here".replace(/-/g,"/"));
```

So the code,

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost/app/blogs'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   angular.forEach(data.posts, function(value, key){
     data.posts[key].created_at = new Date(data.posts[key].created_at.replace(/-/g,"/"));
   }
   $scope.posts = data.posts;
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.posts = [];
});
```

Comment: why not angular forEach

Comment: @Vignesh Yes, I should utilize that.

Answer (score 42):

The date passed to the filter *needs to be of type javascript Date*.

Have you checked what the value `blog.created_at` is displayed as without the filter?

You said your backed service is returning a string representing the date. You can resolve this in two ways:

1. Make your server-side code return a json date object

   - check how the server side code serialize the json that it returns
2. Write your own filter which accepts the string date and returns date in the required format

   - **Note**: you can call the angular filter in your own filter

You can write your own filter as follows:

```js
app.filter('myDateFormat', function myDateFormat($filter){
  return function(text){
    var  tempdate= new Date(text.replace(/-/g,"/"));
    return $filter('date')(tempdate, "MMM-dd-yyyy");
  }
});
```

And use it like this in your template:

```html
<td>
  {{ blog.created_at | myDateFormat }}
</td>
```

Rather than looping through the returned array and then applying the filter

Comment: I have noticed this in some of answers. But how can I achieve this in my ``$http`` call ? Both time I am getting ``2013-10-08 00:00:00``

Comment: Thanks, I have described that I have my date in timestamp format,and I have expected clear code with my snippet. So to convert this I have to use some regex. I have posted my final working result.

Comment: adding split('.')[0] works for me .. so the new tempdate looks likes as -- var  tempdate= new Date((text.replace(/-/g,"/").split('.')[0]));

Comment: there is built in methods for this. Why do you use a framework

Answer (score 9):

you can add a custom Filter which convert string to date, as the following code:

```
app.filter('stringToDate',function ($filter){
    return function (ele,dateFormat){
        return $filter('date')(new Date(ele),dateFormat);
    }
})
```

then use this filter in any template as the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat = "a in data">{{a.created_at |stringToDate:"medium"}}</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create `new Date(/*...*/)` based on fetched data from `$http.get`, like:

```
$scope.date = new Date('2013', '10', '28'); // for example
```

Anyways you can see this Demo in <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z9qmYf6Y61b2XXTKei5A?p=preview)**</kbd>.

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks, I have described that I have my date in timestamp format. So to convert this I have to use some regex. I have posted my final working result.

Answer (score 2):

When record date variable remember to use 'new' keyword as below:

```
var time = new Date();
```

otherwise if you write as this:

```
var time = Date();
```

Date is called as a function and a date time string will be returned which cannot be used as input to the filter.